# React Big Calendar shows only certain range of time

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

Hi am using [React Big Calendar](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar). By default, the calendar show time from 12:00 a.m to 11:30p.m in Week and Day view but i only want to show time range from 7:00 a.m to 7 p.m. I have tried to modify the css by hiding unwanted rows but the event items on the calendar still stay at their old position (e.g: event happens at 7:00 a.m will stay in 10:30 a.m). Here is my scss:

```
.rbc-time-content {
  align-items: normal!important;
  .rbc-time-gutter.rbc-time-column,
  .rbc-day-slot.rbc-time-column {
    .rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+14),
    .rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(n+40):nth-child(-n+48) {
        display: none;
        height: 0!important;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

use the min/max values:

```
<Calendar min={new Date(2020, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0)} max={new Date(2020, 1, 0, 19, 0, 0)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in same problem please use min and max to set specific time range

```
<Calendar
  {...otherProps}
  min={yourMinDateTimeObj}
  max={yourMaxDateTimeObj}
/>
```

Hope this will help